# Camera-related apps crashing

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-1520

I cannot use Nokia camera, 6snap, Twitter... It seems that only apps with camera crash on startup.

But there is a catch: Camera from Microsoft works perfectly!
I do not want to reset my phone, since I have everything set up as I want.
What can I do?
Restart didn't help.

Comment: What phone model is it?

Comment: @Drowin its Lumia 1520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do besides a hard reset is trying to delete and reinstall the apps from the store.
If that doesn't help you should do the hardest, just make sure you backed up your device. This way you won't have to manually reinstall apps and your start screen will also be restored.

Comment: This works, but I won't it mark as answer yet, since I expect more "general solution"

Comment: What would be more general than trying to reinstall the app or doing a hard reset? Btw what exactly worked for you?

Comment: @user1188570 - You should mark this answer for now and if there is any specific answer in future that you come across, you can change your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The new app is called Lumia Camera Classic. This fixed my 1520 that was crashing.